# Android upgrading app

Tags: android, upgrade

I have released ***version 1*** of my app. Now I changed my code and added some more functionality. My question is ***how to update my app in market***. Can anyone just outline the **steps to follow** because i'm confused about *update.zip*.

Moreover I'm using eclipse for my project. **Is there any straight forward way in eclipse (like *export*)?** Please guide me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In your manifest:

  - Change android:versionName to the new visible name
  - increase (important to go up!) android:versionCode
- Build the same .apk as you built when you uploaded app for the first time. Use the same certificate you did the first time
- Upload your .apk using "Upgrade" functionality in market.
- Publish the upgrade

That's it.

Comment: thanks Jarek. what is update.zip mentioned http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-android-update-zip-package/

Comment: It's for updating your android OS not individual apps. The post is misleading - it's not for individual apps at all, it's only for the apps that are embedded as part of the OS installation (like contact, gmail, etc...). It's placed on SD card and then it is picked up by upgrade process, but it is only useful if you control the Android OS distribution and you have distribution certificates.

Comment: VersionCode has to change between versions. That's the way the market detects new versions. Version name can remain, it's more "human oriented". Also note that all this applies to Android Market but works in most alternative markets. The only exception I know of is Amazon that requires you to have a limited set of chars used in the version name.